# How do I free an SSL Connection from OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, openssl

Does the following code properly free all the allocated memory?

```
void foo(){
    //set up connection
    SSL *ssl = NULL;
    SSL_METHOD *method = (SSL_METHOD *)SSLv23_client_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    BIO *bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "facebook.com:443");

    doConnect(ssl, ctx, bio);
    ...
    doFree(ssl, ctx, bio);
}

void doConnect(SSL *ssl, SSL_CTX *ctx, BIO *bio){
    BIO_reset(bio); //this is here in case we are trying to reconnect
    if (BIO_do_connect(connection->bio) <= 0){
        while ( BIO_should_retry(connection->bio)){
            if (BIO_do_connect(connection->bio) > 0){
                break;
            } 
        }
        //error handeling in case BIO_should_retry returns false omitted.
    }
    if (SSL_get_verify_result(connection->ssl) != X509_V_OK){
        // Handle the failed verification
    }
    int socket = BIO_get_fd(bio, NULL);
}

void doFree(SSL *ssl, SSL_CTX *ctx, BIO *bio){
    BIO_free_all(bio); //is this right?
}
```

The reason I'm wondering if this is the correct way of freeing the memory is because I'm currently getting the following stack trace and I dont know if I'm improperly freeing the memory or if it is some other sort of error (valgrind doesnt report any memory error, it simply halts here).

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x040010c2 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  0x06a13a0b in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#2  0x04153ae9 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x041508e4 in BIO_write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#4  0x040771f1 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#5  0x040775ff in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#6  0x04078d2f in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#7  0x04077a64 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#8  0x04074bde in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#9  0x0408eed1 in SSL_shutdown () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#10 0x0409b175 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#11 0x04150638 in BIO_free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#12 0x041511c4 in BIO_free_all () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was freeing the memory properly. It turned out that the issue was a result of me using OpenSSL with threads but not initializing OpenSSLs threading system.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your code doesn't call `SSL_library_init();`. Adding that, the includes, a `main` and removing references to `connection` made it all work for me.

Without  `SSL_library_init();` it crashed in `BIO_should_retry` because `bio` was `NULL`.